# Sorting an array of classes based only on field name

Tags: java, sorting, reflection

I have an application where a user provides me with the name of a field, e.g `name` or `costInCents`, and I have to sort by that field. I have ways of guaranteeing that the field name will be correct. This application causes the complication that I simply cannot make my class `Comparable` and implement a specific `compareTo()`, since with a custom implementation of `compareTo()` I need to know which fields / methods to use at implementation time.

So to achieve this goal, I am trying to use reflection in order to match the field to its accessor. Here's a MWE of what I want to do.

Class `Product` is a simple POJO class whose instances I want to pairwise compare:

```java
public class Product
{

    final String name;
    final Integer quantity;
    final Long costInCents;

    public Product(final String name, final Integer quantity, final Long costInCents)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.costInCents = costInCents;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public Integer getQuantity()
    {
        return quantity;
    }
    public Long getCostInCents()
    {
        return costInCents;
    }
}
```

And my `Main` class, which is currently incomplete:

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Product[] productArray =
                {
                    new Product("Clorox wipes", 50, 700L),
                    new Product("Desk chair", 10, 12000L),
                    new Product("TV", 5, 30000L),
                    new Product("Bookcase", 5, 12000L),
                    new Product("Water bottle", 20, 700L),
                };

        // The following void methods are supposed to sort in-place with something like Arrays.sort() or Collections.sort(),
        // but I am also open to solutions involving stuff like Stream::sorted() or similar ones, which return a sorted array.
        sortByField(productArray, "costInCents");
        sortByField(productArray, "name");
    }

    private void sortByField(final Product[] productArray, final String sorterFieldName)
    {
        final Field sorterField = getSorterField(sorterFieldName, LiteProduct.class); // Gets the Field somehow
        final Method sorterAccessor = getSorterAccessor(sorterField, LiteProduct.class);    // Given the Field, this is easy
        Arrays.sort((Product p1, Product p2)->((Comparable<?>)sorterAccessor.invoke(p1)).compareTo(sorterAccessor.invoke(p2)) > 0); // Capture of ? instead of Object
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the `Arrays.sort()` line results in a compile-time error with message `Capture of ? instead of Object`. I have tried casting the second argument to `Comparable<?>`, `Comparable<? super sorterField.getType()`, etc, with no luck. Ideas?

Comment: `Comparable<? super sorterField.getType()` couldn't work because getType performed at runtime while generic type should be specified at compilation time. Why not just to add enum with field names allowed for ordering and specify the corresponding Comparator? It's pure strategy pattern and no need for reflection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Possibly the best way - with sorting strategies. No need for reflection, compatible with more complex sorting logic:

```
Map<String, Comparator<Product>> sortingStrategies = new HashMap<>(){
    {
        put("costInCents", Comparator.comparingLong(p->p.costInCents));
        put("quantity", Comparator.comparingLong(p->p.quantity));
        put("name", Comparator.comparing(p->p.name));
    }
};

private void sortByField(final Product[] productArray, final String sorterFieldName)
{
    Arrays.sort(productArray, sortingStrategies.get(sorterFieldName));
}
```

Comment: quite similar, but nicer with the comparators, my upvote you have

Comment: Thank you for the response. Considering that I do not know a priori what my fields are going to be, I think a loop over the results of `Product.getFields()` which will then populate the Map might be necessary. Thank you once again.

Comment: @Qwer Izuken would it be an implementation hit, so to speak, if you were to use `Comparator.comparing` in the instances above where you were using `Comparator.comparingIng/Long`? Asking for reasons of automation of your sorting strategies implementation.

Comment: Actually it’s even better to use Comparator.compare for Long wrapper class. But if you you have primitive long, you should use comparingLong.

Answer (score 2):

You could write a Comparator for each field and use it by name via a Map:

```
public class Product
{
    private final static Map<String,Comparator<Product>> COMPARATORS;

    static {
        COMPARATORS = new HashMap<>();
        COMPARATORS.put("name", new NameComparator());
        COMPARATORS.put("costInCents", new CostInCentsComparator());
    }

    final String name;
    final Integer quantity;
    final Long costInCents;

    public Product(final String name, final Integer quantity, final Long costInCents)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.costInCents = costInCents;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public Integer getQuantity()
    {
        return quantity;
    }
    public Long getCostInCents()
    {
        return costInCents;
    }

    static class NameComparator implements Comparator<Product> {

        @Override
        public int compare(Product o1, Product o2) {
            return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
        }

    }

    static class CostInCentsComparator implements Comparator<Product> {

        @Override
        public int compare(Product o1, Product o2) {
            return o1.getCostInCents().compareTo(o2.getCostInCents());
        }

    }

    static Comparator<Product> getComparator(String name) {
        return COMPARATORS.get(name);
    }

}
```

and use that in the main class

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Product[] productArray =
                {
                    new Product("Clorox wipes", 50, 700L),
                    new Product("Desk chair", 10, 12000L),
                    new Product("TV", 5, 30000L),
                    new Product("Bookcase", 5, 12000L),
                    new Product("Water bottle", 20, 700L),
                };

        // The following void methods are supposed to sort in-place with something like Arrays.sort() or Collections.sort(),
        // but I am also open to solutions involving stuff like Stream::sorted() or similar ones, which return a sorted array.
        sortByField(productArray, "costInCents");
        sortByField(productArray, "name");
    }

    private static void sortByField(final Product[] productArray, final String sorterFieldName)
    {
        Arrays.sort(productArray, Product.getComparator(sorterFieldName));
    }
}
```

You may have to do minor changes like makeing it null safe or something

Comment: An approach similar to the accepted one, with just a bit more code :) Thank you @Turo.

Comment: @Jason The advantage of this code is that Product knows its sortable fields, and the respnsability is only there(with a new field, only Product changes, not Main. And no need of reflection),  so I think a combiniation would be the best :-)

Answer (score -1):

you can try this:

```
public class Test{
  public static void main(String arg[]){
  final Product[] productArray =
            {
                new Product("Clorox wipes", 50, 700L),
                new Product("Desk chair", 10, 12000L),
                new Product("TV", 5, 30000L),
                new Product("Bookcase", 5, 12000L),
                new Product("Water bottle", 20, 700L),
            };
            
      Arrays.sort(productArray,(p1, p2) -> p1.getName().compareTo(p2.getName()));
 
     for(Product p: productArray){
        System.out.println(p.getName());
     }
    }
   }
```

in this case Comparator is a functional interface so I used lambad expression. but you can do this too

Comment: This answer exemplifies why I _cannot_ use this approach: I need to sort by a field whose name is provided by the user. Your approach just sorts by name.

Comment: @Jason ok. I undrestood bad.

Comment: you can create two implementations of Comparator and use what you want, after all have ways of guaranteeing that the field whose name is provided by the user will be correct