# Spring JPA sorting and Arrays / List sorting disagree on ties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, sorting, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Suppose that we have the following simple `Entity` called `Product`:

```java
@Data
@Entity
@Builder(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
@NoArgsConstructor // Required for Entities
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Product
{
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Integer quantity;
    private Integer costInUSD;
}
```

Since this is an `Entity`, let's also create a dummy `JPARepository` - extending interface:

```java
@Component
public interface ProductRepo extends JpaRepository<Product, Long>
{
}
```

The following experiment will create a list of 7 products, some of which will have the same values for their fields. Then, it will insert them into our JPA Repo. Then, it will call `findAll(Pageable)` on the Repo, and will also sort the list of original `Product`s based on the exact same field used inside the `Pageable`. As you will see, the two sorted results disagree on some of the aforementioned "ties".

Here is the top-level test, which currently `assert`s nothing and I'm just using it as a convenient "entry point" for this example:

```java
    @Test
    public void testSorting()
    {

        final List<Product> products = Arrays.asList(new Product(1L, "Bic Fountain Pen", 100, 3),
                                                     new Product(2L, "Adidas Soccer Ball", 20, 15),
                                                     new Product(3L, "PetCo Dog Leash", 5, 15), // Same costInUSD as second product
                                                     new Product(4L, "College Life Spiral Notebook", 20, 3), // Same quantity as second product
                                                     new Product(5L, "Shure microphone", 3, 50),
                                                     new Product(6L, "DIYDespair Demotivational poster", 100, 75), // Same quantity as 1
                                                     new Product(7L, "Beautiful Thoughts diary", 100, 3)); // Same quantity *and* costinUSD as 1.
        productRepo.saveAll(products);
        final Map<String, Comparator<Product>> sortingStrategiesMap = buildSortingStrategies();
        sortAndPrint(products, productRepo, "name", sortingStrategiesMap);
        sortAndPrint(products, productRepo, "quantity", sortingStrategiesMap);
        sortAndPrint(products, productRepo, "costInUSD", sortingStrategiesMap);
    }
```

All the private methods used are below:

```java
   // The following method owed to the accepted answer @ 
     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65203606/sorting-an-array-of-classes-based-only-on-field-name/65204148?noredirect=1#comment115288285_65204148
    private Map<String, Comparator<Product>> buildSortingStrategies()
    {
        return new HashMap<>()
        {
            {
                // Ideally I would loop over Product's fields with reflection and make an entry
                // for each one, but let's keep things simple for now.
                put("id", Comparator.comparingLong(Product::getId));
                put("name", Comparator.comparing(Product::getName));
                put("quantity", Comparator.comparingInt(Product::getQuantity));
                put("costInUSD", Comparator.comparingInt(Product::getCostInUSD));
            }
        };
    }

    private void sortAndPrint(final List<Product> productList, final ProductRepo productRepo, final String sorterField,
                              final Map<String, Comparator<Product>> sortingStrategyMap)
    {
        // Page of size 7 to fit all the products in one page. It's the sorting that's
        // the problem here, not the pagination itself.
        final Page<Product> paginatedResult = productRepo.findAll(PageRequest.of(0, 7, Sort.by(sorterField).ascending()));
        productList.sort(sortingStrategyMap.get(sorterField));      // Sorts in place
        System.out.println("======================= PAGE SORTED BY " + sorterField.toUpperCase() + "=================================================== \n" + lineByLine(paginatedResult) + "\n");
        System.out.println("======================= LIST SORTED BY " + sorterField.toUpperCase() + "=================================================== \n" + lineByLine(productList) + "\n");
    }

    private String lineByLine(final Iterable<Product> iterable)
    {
        final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for(Product product : iterable)
        {
            stringBuilder.append(product.toString()).append("\n");
        }
        stringBuilder.deleteCharAt(stringBuilder.length() - 1); // Delete last newline
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
```

And below you can see the results of the prints generated from the `sortAndPrint` calls:

```sh
======================= PAGE SORTED BY NAME=================================================== 
Product(id=2, name=Adidas Soccer Ball, quantity=20, costInUSD=15)
Product(id=7, name=Beautiful Thoughts diary, quantity=100, costInUSD=3)
Product(id=1, name=Bic Fountain Pen, quantity=100, costInUSD=3)
Product(id=4, name=College Life Spiral Notebook, quantity=20, costInUSD=3)
Product(id=6, name=DIYDespair Demotivational poster, quantity=100, costInUSD=75)
Product(id=3, name=PetCo Dog Leash, quantity=5, costInUSD=15)
Product(id=5, name=Shure microphone, quantity=3, costInUSD=50)

======================= LIST SORTED BY NAME=================================================== 
Product(id=2, name=Adidas Soccer Ball, quantity=20, costInUSD=15)
Product(id=7, name=Beautiful Thoughts diary, quantity=100, costInUSD=3)
Product(id=1, name=Bic Fountain Pen, quantity=100, costInUSD=3)
Product(id=4, name=College Life Spiral Notebook, quantity=20, costInUSD=3)
Product(id=6, name=DIYDespair Demotivational poster, quantity=100, costInUSD=75)
Product(id=3, name=PetCo Dog Leash, quantity=5, costInUSD=15)
Product(id=5, name=Shure microphone, quantity=3, costInUSD=50)

======================= PAGE SORTED BY QUANTITY=================================================== 
Product(id=5, name=Shure microphone, quantity=3, costInUSD=50)
Product(id=3, name=PetCo Dog Leash, quantity=5, costInUSD=15)
Product(id=4, name=College Life Spiral Notebook, quantity=20, costInUSD=3)
Product(id=2, name=Adidas Soccer Ball, quantity=20, costInUSD=15)
Product(id=7, name=Beautiful Thoughts diary, quantity=100, costInUSD=3)
Product(id=6, name=DIYDespair Demotivational poster, quantity=100, costInUSD=75)
Product(id=1, name=Bic Fountain Pen, quantity=100, costInUSD=3)

======================= LIST SORTED BY QUANTITY=================================================== 
Product(id=5, name=Shure microphone, quantity=3, costInUSD=50)
Product(id=3, name=PetCo Dog Leash, quantity=5, costInUSD=15)
Product(id=2, name=Adidas Soccer Ball, quantity=20, costInUSD=15)
Product(id=4, name=College Life Spiral Notebook, quantity=20, costInUSD=3)
Product(id=7, name=Beautiful Thoughts diary, quantity=100, costInUSD=3)
Product(id=1, name=Bic Fountain Pen, quantity=100, costInUSD=3)
Product(id=6, name=DIYDespair Demotivational poster, quantity=100, costInUSD=75)

======================= PAGE SORTED BY COSTINUSD=================================================== 
Product(id=7, name=Beautiful Thoughts diary, quantity=100, costInUSD=3)
Product(id=4, name=College Life Spiral Notebook, quantity=20, costInUSD=3)
Product(id=1, name=Bic Fountain Pen, quantity=100, costInUSD=3)
Product(id=2, name=Adidas Soccer Ball, quantity=20, costInUSD=15)
Product(id=3, name=PetCo Dog Leash, quantity=5, costInUSD=15)
Product(id=5, name=Shure microphone, quantity=3, costInUSD=50)
Product(id=6, name=DIYDespair Demotivational poster, quantity=100, costInUSD=75)

======================= LIST SORTED BY COSTINUSD=================================================== 
Product(id=4, name=College Life Spiral Notebook, quantity=20, costInUSD=3)
Product(id=7, name=Beautiful Thoughts diary, quantity=100, costInUSD=3)
Product(id=1, name=Bic Fountain Pen, quantity=100, costInUSD=3)
Product(id=3, name=PetCo Dog Leash, quantity=5, costInUSD=15)
Product(id=2, name=Adidas Soccer Ball, quantity=20, costInUSD=15)
Product(id=5, name=Shure microphone, quantity=3, costInUSD=50)
Product(id=6, name=DIYDespair Demotivational poster, quantity=100, costInUSD=75)
```

Unsurprisingly, when sorting by name, the two lists are identical: there are no ties in the `name` field of the `Product` instances. However, when sorting by `quantity` and `costInCents`, you can see for yourselves that ties tend to be treated differently! This means that the implementation of `JPARepository::findAll(Pageable)` does **not** treat ties the same way that `Arrays::sort()` or `Collection::sort()` does.

Is there any way to achieve consistency between the two results? It could be important for testing an API I'm building.

Comment: I didn't look that close but off the top of my head would not the order of sorting ties be undefined?

Comment: You are using Spring JPA. You can rely on `PagingAndSortingRepository` interface.

Comment: @K.Nicholas is this something that is guaranteed in the docs? I have not been able to find it.

@MarcosBarbero `JPARepository` extends `PagingAndSortingRepository`!

Comment: Not sure I follow. Why should resolving ties when sorting be the same with Java and your RDBMS? JPA cannot guarantee you anything, because it's the database doing the sorting

Comment: @crizzis I understand your argument. I was originally thinking that because the instances were of the same type, that the decision of how to treat a tie ought to be the same between the database and the application. But it is not the object itself that determines this. After all, the object in question is *not* `Comparable` and there is no call to a commonly accessible `compareTo()` or `equals()` implementation. Flawed line of thinking. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Answered by @crizzis in the comments of OP.